# Name of the solid built on a sphere's surface

Tags: geometry, spheres, solid-geometry

I don't know the name of the solid built on a sphere's surface. I mean, given a sphere of radius r1, create another sphere with the same origin and radius $r_2$, with $r_2 > r_1$. I'm interested in the solid that results when you "subtract" the first sphere from the second one.

If we were in 2D the object would be a ring.

Comment: Shell.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a [spherical shell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_shell).